# How do I change the current line highlight background in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, caret

The question says it all. I need the place to style the current line highlight.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Under settings:

```
IDE Settings
    |
    Editor
       |
       Colors & Fonts
           |
           General
              |
              Caret Row
```

Comment: For PyCharm 5 on Mac its found in the PyCharm->Preferences->Editor->Colors & Fonts->General->Editor->Caret Row

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Another way that seems like it should always work is just searching settings for `caret row`

Answer (score 8):

1. PyCharm
2. Preferences
3. Editor
4. Colors & Fonts
5. General
6. Editor
7. Caret Row

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

On a more modern version of PyCharm, it is found in the Settings under **Editor > Color Scheme > General** | Caret row.

To remove the highlight, go to File / Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> [PC] / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> [Mac]) and uncheck the Background checkbox as shown in the image below:

[image: IDE settings dialogue]